# Wordpress Rest api and ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible for an Ionic application to fetch data from multiple WordPress REST APIs based on certain conditions like user login? Can the Ionic app fetch data from multiple headless WordPress REST APIs and display them on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it is possible to make rest api using wordpress
> Create Custom Plugin for you rest api
> Make a file and add this code in plugin and then activate the plugin from wp-admin

```
/*
    Plugin URI: http://www.test.com/
    Description: Develope Rest API for mobile interaction
    Author: test
    Version: 1.1.1
    Author URI: http://www.test.com/
    Text Domain: test_custom
    Domain Path: /languages
    Network: true
  */
```

> Now add rest routes in it by adding code, It will create post method

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('julisa/v1', 'login', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'test',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ));
});
```

> Now make function for your route

```
public function test(WP_REST_Request $request){
   return "test";
 }
```

> Now type your business login and enjoy it.